# Spring micrometer tracing not propagating x-correlation-id correctly

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, micrometer, distributed-tracing

I have moved my applications to spring boot 3.1.5. I am using ***spring-boot-starter-actuator-3.1.5*** which pulls in ***io.micrometer*** specific dependencies of version 1.11.5

I face the following issue while triggering an api call.

1.`Request 1 with correlationId cr1 yields correct correlationId in the response ie. cr1`

2.`Request 2 with correlationId cr2 yields incorrect correlationId in the response ie cr1`

I am not sure where these correlationId values are cached and interchanged. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Something might be happening in your app since as far as I remember we don't add any w3c or b3 headers to the response.